# How can i get UIButtons created in loop to hide

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created 8 buttons in a loop that line up 4 rows by 2 columns,
which when clicked present individual tags which i can use in a
switch. However i can not seems to hide all of the buttons after i am
finished with them. I would like to click on a spearate button that
will delete hide or remove them all.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong)  UIButton *ventButtons;

@end
//UIButton *ventButtons; // <--- this works with or with out does not affect outcome..?? Do i need this in xcode 6?
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize ventButtons;
```

My Code

```
int x = 260;     
int y = 200;

for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) { // create 8 buttons

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [self setVentButtons:button];
    [button setTag:j];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 20, 20); 

    if (j == 1 || j == 3 || j == 5 || j == 7) {  
        [button setTitle: @"▶️" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        y = y + 20;
        x = x - 40;
    } else { 
        [button setTitle: @"◀️" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        y = y - 10;
    }

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(getVentValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:ventButtons];

    y=y+10;
    x=x+20;
```

When ran all the buttons show individual tags when clicked, however if
i try to hide or remove a tagged button(s) using the selector it will
not hide tagged button using the code below, nothing happens.

```
NSLog(@"Vent Button tag: %ld",(long)[sender tag]);

[[self.ventButtons viewWithTag:3] setHidden:YES];
```

Ive also tried removing the buttons like this and it only removes the
last button created, which is button tag 7.

```
- (void)getVentValue:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"Vent Button tag: %ld",(long)[sender tag]);
    [self.ventButtons removeFromSuperview];
    self.ventButtons = nil;
    ..
```

I Think i need to use an array but i have no idea how to set that up.
I was hoping there was a way to use a property variable and select the
desired buttons within via tag. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: yes, array would be the best option. But you can also get the tags to work, you should use the following line: `[[self.view viewWithTag:3] setHidden:YES];`

Comment: @luk2302 I've already tried that and it does work. What i need is an example of how to use an array to do this. You have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This code (`[[self.ventButtons viewWithTag:3] setHidden:YES];`) will not work because you are searching `viewWithTag` of three(3) inside your selected/active `button`

doing this: (`[[self.view viewWithTag:3] setHidden:YES];`) will do the work..

But if you want to use array you add it along with the loop like:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // global variable

for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
{
    ..

    [arrayButtons addObject:button];

    // or
    //to keep the most recent created button in index 0
    [arrayButtons insertObject:button atIndex:0]; 
    // in the array button arrangement would be: ["button8", "button7", "button6"..];

    ..
}
```

and hiding it like:

```
//to avoid warning: cast the kind of class
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[arrayButtons objectAtindex:3];
button.hidden = YES;

// or simply
[[arrayButtons objectAtIndex:3] setHidden:YES];
```

---

Another concern is:

You are adding `[self.view addSubview:ventButtons];` what is that? an array of buttons? or maybe a container of all the buttons?

```
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) { // create 8 buttons

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    // [self setVentButtons:button];  ? what is this ? 
    [button setTag:j];

    ..

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(getVentValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // do this instead since you already set everything for the button
    [self.view addSubview:button]; // previous code: [self.view addSubview:ventButtons];
```

and you can also hide them all using `for-statement`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    [[self.view viewWithTag:i] setHidden:YES];
```

and also:

```
- (void)getVentValue:(id)sender 
{
    // You are logging the tag of the sender
    NSLog(@"Vent Button tag: %ld",(long)[sender tag]);

    // and you are working with this `self.ventButtons`
    // [self.ventButtons removeFromSuperview];
    // self.ventButtons = nil;
    ..

    Why not?
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    button.hidden = YES;

    //or

    [(UIButton *)sender setHidden:YES];
```

**Note:**

But i'm suggesting you keep on working with tags, it is the best option for your implementation. Memory wise option.

Hope this will help you, Cheers.. :)

Comment: An array would be a waste of memory, you dont need it since the UIButtons are already added to the View and it holds a strong reference to them.

Comment: Yes that would be me advice as well.. using tags is the best option since he already set the tags.

Comment: Agree, also if he needs a reference to the button when its tapped, you already got it for free "(id)sender" see my answer

Comment: Yeah, i've seen your code above, but why would you use `id` ? you can simply use `(UIButton *)sender` and not do the casting of class.. an im confused.. why just want to hide the button but he is doing `removeFromSuperview`, anyway using array and retrieving object from array using tags attached to the actual object is really a waste..

Comment: Yes you could also just cast it if you are only using it one time, also instead of removing it one could just hide it it thats what he wants

Comment: @Hazneliel Your right about not using the Array I've thrown that out. VentButtons is a property i was trying to place all the buttons inside of so i could get rid of or hide this single property instead of addressing each button with a loop. Now with your suggestion If i use a for loop starting with 0 calling; [[self.view viewWithTag:0]setHidden:YES]; this will get rid of the parent view removing all control. If i start the loop with a 1 it works. I realized that ventButtons was storing just one button which is why i wanted the array. Oh and i like the use of the modulo

Comment: @hodji, since we didnt see what's inside `[self setVentButtons:button];` we cant respond to this comment of yours. :) But glad it works now, Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

You dont need an array, the buttons are already added to the view and you can just iterate them if needed.

However in this case since you want to remove the button when its tapped, you get a reference to it when the getVentValue method is called, that is "sender", so the only thing you have to do is:

```
- (void)getVentValue:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Vent Button tag: %ld",(long)[sender tag]);

    // Button that was tapped
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    [button removeFromSuperview];
    // or if you want to hide it then do
    // button.hidden = YES;
}
```

Also another thing, you dont need that property "ventButtons", you can get rid of that, and since you are iterating and adding buttons every odd number, then you can use the mod operator in your loop:

```
int x = 260;
int y = 200;

for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) { // create 8 buttons

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [button setTag:j];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 20, 20);

    if (j % 2 == 1) {
        [button setTitle: @"▶️" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        y = y + 20;
        x = x - 40;
    } else {
        [button setTitle: @"◀️" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        y = y - 10;
    }

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(getVentValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    y += 10;
    x += 20;
}
```

This should work for you.